# I'm trying to deploy with git to a semi-managed vps, need to write a script to change owners

Tags: shell, shell-script, ssh, scripting, git

I'm trying to deploy my sites on my company's semi-managed vps server using this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps

It works on my own Digital Ocean servers without change, but things are set up differently on my company server.

The public_html folders need to be owned by the whm account user, or you get 500 errors. But the git user needs to own the public_html folder for this method to work. So I'm modifying the post-receive script to include commands to change the owners, but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/sh

# REPLACE *** WITH ACCOUNT USERNAME
# Change owner of html folder to git
find /home/***/public_html -user root -exec chown -R git:git {} + 2>>logfile
echo "Changed owner to git."

# Update html folder with git push contents
git --work-tree=/home/***/public_html --git-dir=/home/***/repo/live.git checkout -f
echo "Updated public html."

# Restore ownership of directories
find /home/***/public_html -user root -exec chown -R ***:*** {} + 2>>logfile
find /home/***/public_html -user root -exec chown ***:nobody {} + 2>>logfile
echo "Changed owners back."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do away with find; since you know where the directory is, you should just deal with it directly. The find command introduces a new condition that could fail.

In either case, you are not terminating the find command, which could be a problem.

This might work better:

```
#!/bin/sh

# REPLACE foo WITH ACCOUNT USERNAME
# Change owner of html folder to git
chown -R git:git /home/foo/public_html || echo "$date I failed." >> /tmp/foo.log
echo "Changed owner to git."

# Update html folder with git push contents
git --work-tree=/home/foo/public_html --git-dir=/home/foo/repo/live.git checkout -f || echo "$date Git failed." >> /tmp/foo.log
echo "Updated public html."

# Restore ownership of directories
chown -R foo:bar /home/foo/public_html 
chown foo:nobody /home/foo/public_html
echo "Changed owners back."
```

Comment: Thanks! I did have to add sudo to the chown commands for it to allow git to do it, which makes it ask for a password, but that's a small price for git deploy convenience imo. Unless doing it as sudoer is insecure somehow? We only have two developers, myself included, and I trust the other guy.

Comment: Adding yourself to the group that inherently has permission to write to that directory would be a more direct way of making that happen, but sudo ("switch user and do...") is the obvious work-around if you don't want to do that.